# How can I install "MulVAL- an attack graph generation toolkit" and make it work?

Tags: windows, cygwin

How can I install "MulVAL- an attack graph generation toolkit" and make it work?

MulVAL- is a logic-based attack graph generation technique invented by Xinming Ou. I have installed "MulVAL" as per the instructions given in (http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~xou/argus/software/mulval/readme.html) and tried to run it for the testcase given in input file (input.P) as follows:

I am using cygwin : graph_gen.sh mulval/testcases/3host/input.P -v

But I am getting the following error:

cat: goals.txt: No such file or directory

rm: cannot remove `goals.txt': No such file or directory

The attack simulation encountered an error.

Please check xsb_log.txt.

What does it mean and how do I solve it? Any kind of help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem. You must add xsb path into the PATH.
eg. I'm using CentOS and have my xsb in my HOME dir hence in my bash_profile:

```
# set variables for xsb
export XSBROOT="$HOME/XSB"
export PATH="$XSBROOT/bin:$XSBROOT/utils:$PATH"
```